# MySQL curious duplicates issue

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL members table with names and addresses, and need to find those rows with duplicate addresses. I do this successfully with a query using GROUP BY.  The curiosity is that it produces an output of 300+ rows of duplicate addresses, as expected, but includes just one record as being a duplicate when it isn't. If I add a GROUP_CONCAT to the query it lists the same unique id number twice for this row.  Any ideas why this should happen?

Comment: It's very likely your table contains some sort of near-duplicate data for that one strange record. Beyond that observation, it's very hard to help you without some sample data and a sample query. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: A combination of name+address is hardly unique and you're just looking for "duplicate addresses"? I assume you meant to look for _"same name (or a unique identifier) with duplicate addresses"_

Comment: Apologies for posting this.  Rookie mistake in the WHERE filter I had added - the record in question was able to satisfy conditions twice, so was deemed a duplicate.